# generating pages through a single literal control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What if I use one literal control and assign to it - a string, dynamically built for the whole html page in it's code behind file? Will the literal control modify the output in any way? e.g. add extra html, encoding etc

E.g. ASPX file will contain just this

```
<%
@Page Language="VB"
Title="SamplePage"
CodeFile="SamplePageCodeBehind.aspx.vb"
Inherits="SamplePage"
%><asp:Literal Id="litContents" Runat="Server" />
```

And in the codebehind (SamplePageCodeBehind.aspx.vb):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(
  ByVal sender As Object,
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs
) Handles Me.Load

  Dim sHtml As String = _
  "<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>"

  litContents.Text = sHtml

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with Visual Studio? And, if you want to quickly create code that cannot be maintained, you've found a pretty good way of doing that.

Comment: nothing wrong with visual studio, just wondering if a literal control does anything to the raw text i'm sending to the browser

Comment: And, you're aware that ASP.NET is designed to produce dynamic pages, based on db, templates, etc?

Comment: yes i'm aware. this is a question about the literal control. not about best practices.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify. You _did_ ask about downsides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the literal control, you could take the complete control over your rendering

```
 Response.Clear()
 Response.Write("any html string")
 Response.Flush()
 Response.End()
```

in your Page_Load method. This way you could be sure that no unwanted tags are rendered.